# Java regex replaceAll

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove `\s*,\s*` but only when it's not between `"`.
For example, this string `a, b  , c, "a, b ,   , c," a ,,` should look like `abc"a, b ,   , c," a`.

As I found out `[^abc]` means don't touch `abc` and `\.*` means everything so I tried this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\"\\.*,\\.*\"]\\s*,\\s*", "");
```

Important: amount of `"` is even.

Comment: "`\\.*` means everything" - It actually will repeat the `.` character.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought `.` means any symbol.

Comment: It's escaped, so it will be `.` _literally_.

Comment: Do you mean it gonna work? `replaceAll("[^\".*,.*\"]\\s*,\\s*", "")`
It doesn't.

Comment: Not very obvious with regexes; classical tools here would be better (indexOf etc). Also, what must be done if you have, say, `a,b, "a, b`?

Comment: Can you define 'only when it's not between `"`'? What should happen it there's an odd number of `"`?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat Yes, let me edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this pattern

```
\s*,\s*(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/152)
and I guess in your case, replace `\s` with `\\s`

```
\s*,\s*                 # your pattern
(?=                     # look-ahead
    (?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*  # optional pairs of double quotes
    [^"]*$              # followed by optional anything but double quotes to the end
)
```

Comment: explanation posted above.

Comment: Thank you. You've helped me so much. =)